# python webscraping pricing and hidden elements with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

In this webpage: [https://www.centris.ca/en/properties~for-sale~brossard?view=Thumbnail](https://www.centris.ca/en/properties%7Efor-sale%7Ebrossard?view=Thumbnail)

I am trying to do two things:

1. get the price of the listings
2. get the MLS number of the listings

```
from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time 

url = 'https://www.centris.ca/en/properties~for-sale~brossard?view=Thumbnail'


def scrap_pages(driver):
    listings = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'description')

    if listings[-1].text.split('/n')[0] == '': del listings[-1]

    for listing in listings:
        print(listing.text.split('\n'))
        price = listing.text.split('\n')[0]

        prop_type = listing.text.split('\n')[1]
        addr = listing.text.split('\n')[2]
        city = listing.text.split('\n')[3]
        sector = listing.text.split('\n')[4]
        bedrooms = listing.text.split('\n')[5]
        bathrooms = listing.text.split('\n')[6]

        listing_item = {
            'price': price,
            'Address': addr,
            'property Type': prop_type,
            'city': city,
            'bedrooms': bedrooms,
            'bathrooms': bathrooms,
            'sector': sector

        }

        centris_list.append(listing_item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    #chrome_options.add_argument("headless")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
    centris_list=[]

    driver.get(url) 

    total_pages = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'pager-current').text.split('/')[1].strip() 
    
    for i in range(1,int(total_pages)):
        scrap_pages(driver)
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.next> a').click()
        time.sleep(0.8)
```

my code above already gets the price, but not in a way I would like. I don't like the fact that I had to get the whole description, and then go through the whole text/split/list selection. I tried to grab the price via one of the following methods below but none of it worked. They all returned unable to find element error. and if I can get price to work I might be able to adapt it the rest of the data too.

```
#price= listing.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'price').text  
#price= listing.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="divMainResult"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/div[2]/span[1]').text  
#price= listing.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="divMainResult"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/div[2]/meta[2]').text  
#price = listing.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#divMainResult > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.description > a > div.price').text
```

the 2nd part of the question, getting the MLS number, unforunately I was never able to get it working, they all returned unable to find element error. But if I look at the HTML source of the webpage, I can see each listing does come with a MLS number: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX1rE.jpg

```
#mls= listing.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'MlsNumberNoStealth').text
#mls = listing.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#MlsNumberNoStealth').text 
#mls = listing.find_element(By.ID, 'MlsNumberNoStealth').text 
#mls = listing.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="MlsNumberNoStealth"]/p').text 
#mls = listing.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'div') 
#mls = listing.find_elements(By.ID, 'MlsNumberNoStealth')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close to the right approach.
Once you have a `listings` elements list by this line `listings = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'description')` you can iterate over the listings and grab their prices and MLSs as following:

```py
def scrap_pages(driver):
    listings = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'description')

    for listing in listings:
        price = listing.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='price']/meta[@itemprop='price']").text
        mls = listing.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@id='MlsNumberNoStealth']/p").text
```

All the other details can be grabbed in the similar manner.

Comment: thx, with your examples I got rid of almost all the parse/splits!

Comment: You are welcome! In case there are still any problems / things to be improved you are welcome to ask more questions and we will try to help

Comment: hi @Prophet hmm so this is interesting... I am not sure what changed but sometime during the last week i am not able to get the price or the MLS again... still the same code. https://github.com/jzoudavy/webScrap_Selenium/blob/main/test.py

no errors, just returns blank

Comment: Currently I am not near my computer, so it would be better if you open a new question for that. When I get home I will see, if the question will still be open and I can help I will try

Comment: I saw your new question and someone's answer. You wrote there you need to check it. Let me know if problem resolved

Comment: problem is solved, we are using following-sibling and get attribute no instead of reading what's under p or itemprop's text value. still not sure why it stopped working the html looks the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an excellent programmer, but I work extensively with HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I believe you could link an executable Javascript file that went through something like...

```js
h1.style.display = "block"
```

```css
h1 {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1 id="h1">Hidden data</h1>
</body>
```